# Taking spesific elements from the array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on Visual Studio about Python 3 Project. The user enter a number `01102003060d8090a305` 
Then I separate the numbers looks like: `['01', '10', '20', '03', '06', '0d', '80', '90', 'a3', '05']` and take the fourd element of the list with this code:

```
dynamic_array = [ ]
hexdec = input("Enter even number ");
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_array = strArray
print(dynamic_array)
print(dynamic_array[3])
```

So, I want to take third element of `03` be an integer and after sixth element of array show with continou three element looks like: `03 80 90 a3` 
If the integer change, it stills going after sixth element but show only number of elements include integer for example `02 80 90`
Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isdigit() to verify if you have number or letter in your array :

```
dynamic_array = [ ]
hexdec = input("Enter even number ");
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_array = strArray
if dynamic_array[3].isdigit():
    endValue = dynamic_array[3]
    print dynamic_array[3]
    for i in range(6,6+int(endValue)):
        print dynamic_array[i]
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer @Fabrice, your solution seems like correct but I want to have dynamic interval about ´(6:9)´ for example if the user enter ´04´ then it will change ´(6:10)´

Comment: Ok @Asell, you can put the result in a variable (used as int) to dynamically change the output (answer edited)

Comment: Thank you so much @Fabrice but one more thing because of I couldn't see 03 in the output :/

Comment: You can add print dynamic_array[3], before the for loop

Comment: Thank you so much @Fabrice you are awesome, you safe my life!

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the `dynamic_array` list and use generic unpacking to form a new list:

```
n = dynamic_array[3]
print([n, *dynamic_array[6 : 6 + int(n)]])
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer @blhsing your solution is correct but how to I take output instead of `['03', '80', '90', 'a3']`, only looks like : `03 80 90 a3`

Comment: If you want to output `03 80 90 a3` you can do: `' '.join((n, *dynamic_array[6 : 6 + int(n)]))`

Comment: Thank you so much  @blhsing it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
num = dynamic_array[3]
integer_array = [num]
for i in dynamic_array[6:]:
    if i.isdigit():
        integer_array.append(i)
print(' '.join(integer_array[:int(num) + 1]))
```

Comment: First of all thank you for solution @C.K. but it doesn't take`a3`

Comment: Well @Asell, if you just mean that when the 3rd element is `03`, the output can be letters and integers, while when the 3rd element is other integer, such as `02`, there should be only integers in the output?